# JackRabbit Webdav Client is compatible with Httpclient 3.0

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit

I have used Jackrabbit webdav client for caldav function with Httpclient 3.x. now i want to upgrade the Httpclient 4.x. how can it be done in simple way

Answer (score 1):

It needs changes in Jackrabbit. See open ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2406

Comment: Thank you julian. I stardted changinh the jackrabbit src but it created more problem. so is there any other easy way like adding patch.